# How do I draw an elliptic curve?

Tags: geometry, plane-curves

I can draw a circle using a compass.

I can draw an ellipse using two focal points and a loop of string.

I think that you can draw an arbitrary conic with a "generalized" compass for which the pencil can slide in and out as it is rotated.

What instruments and devices can draw elliptic curves?

Comment: I wonder why people are upvoting this facetious answer..

Comment: Elliptic curves such as $y^2=x^3-x$ have two components. Could a device plot both components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an answer, for a limited case, and it is not pretty. Elliptic curves have the form:

$y^2= x^3 + ax +b$

Suppose $b=0$ and $a < 0$

$y^2= x(x^2 + a)$

$y= \sqrt{x}\sqrt{x^2 + a}$

You can construct $\sqrt{x}$ as shown [here](http://www.cs.cas.cz/portal/AlgoMath/Geometry/PlaneGeometry/GeometricConstructions/SquareSquareRootConstruction.htm).

[image]

And, $\sqrt{x^2 + a}$  with $a < 0$ is the distance from (x, -a) to the origin.

We have two constructible lengths so just construct their product:

[image]

...and you have y.

Comment: That's quite neat but am I right in thinking it only lets us construct a single point at a time rather than tracing out part of the curve?

Comment: Yes. This would be quite tedious. Though, there may be some way of streamlining it. The constructions have so many similarities. I've added some images to show this.

Answer (score 3):

[This thesis](http://www.a-kobel.de/kempe/thesis.pdf) looks like it may be of considerable interest.